# Dynamic button on click event only applies to last button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, dynamic, greasemonkey

I'm trying to have a div be hidden, and it's contents toggled when it's corresponding button is pressed. There appears to be many ways to add an on click event, but each one that has worked for me only works for the last button in the list.

This as it is creates a list of 10 buttons, and only the last button shows it's hidden text when ran. The rest of the buttons appear to have no action or error when clicked.  Commented out are other attempts at getting this to work.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        ToggleDivPlz
// @namespace   ToggleDivPlz
// @include     */mypage.html
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
function ToggleDiv(sToggleDiv) {
  console.log('in ToggleDiv and is ' + sToggleDiv.replace('btn', 'div'));
  var thisdiv = document.getElementById(sToggleDiv.replace('btn', 'div'));
  if (thisdiv.style.display == 'block')
  thisdiv.style.display = 'none';
   else
  thisdiv.style.display = 'block';
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  //create a button and div with paired names
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML +
  '<button id="btn' + i + '">Show/Hide div' + i + '</button>' +
  '<div class="mydivs" id="div' + i + '" style="display:none">This text starts hidden, but the button shows it.</div><br /><br />';

  //The last element gets this onclick. All previous elements are not set correctly.
  document.getElementById("btn" + i).onclick = (function() {
    ToggleDiv(this.id);
  });

  //doing onclick via the button's text creation throws the error that the method raised doesn't exist. :(
  //document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML +
  //'<button id="btn' + i + '" onclick="ToggleDiv(this.id);">Show/Hide div' + i + '</button>' +
  //'<div class="mydivs" id="div' + i + '" style="display:none">This text starts hidden, but the button shows it.</div><br /><br />';

  //various degrees of similarly wrong to really wrong
  //document.getElementById("btn" + i).on('click', 'button', function() {ToggleDiv(this.id)});
  //document.getElementById("btn" + i).on('click', 'button', console.log('I am ' + this.id));
  //document.getElementById("btn" + i).onclick = function() { ToggleDiv(this.id);  }
  //document.getElementById("btn" + i).addEventListener ( "click", ToggleDiv, this.id );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is this statement:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML +
  '<button id="btn' + i + '">Show/Hide div' + i + '</button>' +
  '<div class="mydivs" id="div' + i + '" style="display:none">This text    starts hidden, but the button shows it.</div><br /><br />';
```

When you do this, you essentially *replace* all the elements in `body` with new elements which have the same HTML code, but which lost any modification you did to the old ones with JavaScript.

A fix would be to instead create your elements via `document.createElement` and then append them with `document.body.appendChild`.
If you're lazy you can also keep that code and put it in a container `div` created via `document.createElement` that you then append:

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = '...';
document.body.appendChild(container);
```

Comment: Due to the locations that my actual code places these button/div combinations being dynamic based on the page the user is on, I found it easiest to run my for loop twice. The first time doing all the replacements of where the divs/buttons should be, then the second to place the on clicks and content within the divs. Thank you for your help 
lleaff. I get to continue my project now. ^.^

Comment: @Aki That sounds like the right approach. You should place code that affects the layout of the page at the top in order to avoid reflows as much as possible: [more info if you're into that](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow?hl=en). And you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this one is already working in my local

```
function ToggleDiv(sToggleDiv) {
  console.log('in ToggleDiv and is ' + sToggleDiv.id.replace('btn','div'));
  var thisdiv = document.getElementById(sToggleDiv.id.replace('btn', 'div'));
  if (thisdiv.style.display == 'block')
    thisdiv.style.display = 'none';
  else
    thisdiv.style.display = 'block';
}
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
//create a button and div with paired names`enter code here`
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML +
'<button id="btn' + i + '" onclick="ToggleDiv(this)">Show/Hide div' + i + '</button>' +  '<div class="mydivs" id="div' + i + '" style="display:none">This text starts hidden, but the button shows it.</div><br /><br />';
}
```

Comment: This works wonderfully for javascript straight. Alas, because I am in Greasemonkey, the page doesn't know what ToggleDiv is as that function is defined in the GM userscript instead of on the page. My first large commented out for loop notes the attempt to do inline onclick declaration.